# How to execute TestNetworkSpeed command for NetworkControl device trait using Google Actions?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I want to execute the [TestNetworkSpeed](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/networkcontrol#action.devices.commands.testnetworkspeed) command which is a part of NetworkControl device trait.
Example in the documentation is the following:

> **Examples**
> What's the Wi-Fi speed?

For [action.devices.SYNC](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync) intent we return the following mocked output:

```
{
      agentUserId: 'userId',
      devices: [
        {
          id: 'deviceId',
          type: 'action.devices.types.NETWORK',
          willReportState: true,
          notificationSupportedByAgent: true,
          name: {
            name: 'ssid',
            defaultNames: ['ssid'],
            nicknames: ['ssid'],
          },
          traits: ['action.devices.traits.NetworkControl'],
          attributes: {
            supportsNetworkDownloadSpeedTest: true,
            supportsNetworkUploadSpeedTest: true,
            supportsEnablingNetworkProfile: true,
            supportsDisablingNetworkProfile: true,
            networkProfiles: ['kids'],
          },
        },
      ],
 }
```

When I execute the utterance from above example Google Assistant does not make a request to my server. It returns generic google results output.

When I execute utterance to turn off / on the internet for profile it works correctly.

We have enabled [HomeGraph](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/homegraph).

Here are additional screenshots to showcase what is happening.

When I ask GA what is my ssid it returns the correct ssid.
[image]

When I ask GA to turn off the internet for device it works correctly.
[image]

When I ask GA what is wifi speed of ssid it returns the SSID name and we receive query command on our api endpoint.
[image]

I changed the name of ssid to "home wifi" and reran the command.
I receive the following default output (it does not hit our endpoint).
[image]

When I execute just what's the wifi speed without ssid name I also receive default output.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your example `EXECUTE` response payload for the `TestNetworkSpeed` command? Are you implementing this with a follow-up response or directly to an execution response?

Comment: @ToniCorinne Google Assistant does not even make a request to our API when we say "What's the Wi-Fi speed?". It just returns a default response, as if we didn't have an action which supports TestNetworkSpeed so there is no EXECUTE request.

Comment: Does your project show any [logs/errors](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging#execution_payload) when that request is made? Can you trigger the EXECUTE request if you explicitly identify the device (i.e., "What's the Wifi speed of ssid?" )

Comment: @ToniCorinne I posted additional pictures to show what is happening. No, our project does not show any errors (if you mean our backend). It does not even reach our backend. Does the google action project have any logs to show why it does not even reach our endpoint?

Comment: @ToniCorinne can I send you my actions on google id and you verify why it does not work?

Comment: Open a bug on the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) and  please include your SYNC and EXECUTE responses in there. I was able to duplicate the issue you're seeing, but it will be easier to follow up on the tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNetworkSpeed currently requires features that are not available on Google Home App / Assistant on mobile surfaces, and only supported on a Google Home device. The team is working to enable more surfaces across all available traits.

You can issue “What’s my Wi-Fi Speed” voice utterance on a Google Home device and see if that’s working instead. If you are having issues, you can open up a request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).